# How do I render a nested Navigation with knockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I'm having a nested array which represents a navigation (see the jsFiddle below). I want to render this navigation with knockoutJS but have no clue how. I already went through the official documentation, but they only cover a simple list/collection.

http://jsfiddle.net/a4swJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding.

**Update:** I removed the containerless foreach and used to foreach option of the template binding instead. Working example below also updated

HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="node-template">
    <li>
       <a data-bind="text: Title, attr:{href: Target}"></a>
       <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'node-template', foreach: Children }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'node-template', foreach: Nodes }"></ul>
```

JS:

```
function NavigationNode(target, title)
{
    var self = this;

    self.Target = target || "[No Target]";
    self.Title = title || "[No Title]";

    self.Children = ko.observableArray([]);
};

function NavigationViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.Nodes = ko.observableArray([]);

    var node1 = new NavigationNode("/parent", "Parent");
    var node2 = new NavigationNode("/parent/sub1", "Sub 1");
    var node3 = new NavigationNode("/parent/sub1/sub2", "Sub 2");

    node2.Children().push(node3);
    node1.Children().push(node2);

    self.Nodes.push(node1);

    ko.applyBindings(this);
};

new NavigationViewModel();​
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4swJ/3/).

Comment: First of all: thank you. This seems to be the right answer. But I have a question left: It looks like you need the HTML comments in the template in order to create some sort of context, right? Is this somewhere documented, because I haven't seen this so far.

Comment: Yes, all of the KO bindings that control descendant bindings (like foreach, if, template etc.) can also be applied to a ko comment in case you do not have a parent container. In some cases it's the only solution as you cannot apply more than one of such bindings to any one element. I updated my answer with a link to the official explanation.